# Unable to connect to local SQL Server Express instance from CodeIgniter 2.1.3, what I am missing?

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I will start saying that I tried almost everything I could found over the Internet included the following list:

- [Connecting to SQL Server via CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20173716/connecting-to-sql-server-via-codeigniter)
- [Codeigniter: How to setup connection to a SQL server (2008)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431447/codeigniter-how-to-setup-connection-to-a-sql-server-2008)
- [CodeIgniter MSSQL connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669337/codeigniter-mssql-connection)
- [CI connect to SQL SERVER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19396611/ci-connect-to-sql-server/19398832#19398832)

What I haven't tried? Use the Microsoft SQL Server extension as many answer says.

Here is how my `database.php` config looks like:

```
$active_group = 'mssql_local';

$db['mssql_local']['hostname'] = 'localhost:1433'; // RNDPC\SQLEXPRESS:1433
$db['mssql_local']['username'] = 'ssUser';
$db['mssql_local']['password'] = '******';
$db['mssql_local']['database'] = 'ssDB';
$db['mssql_local']['dbdriver'] = 'mssql';
$db['mssql_local']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['mssql_local']['pconnect'] = false;
$db['mssql_local']['db_debug'] = false;
$db['mssql_local']['cache_on'] = false;
$db['mssql_local']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['mssql_local']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['mssql_local']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['mssql_local']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['mssql_local']['autoinit'] = true;
$db['mssql_local']['stricton'] = false;
$db['mssql_local']['port']     = 1433;
```

But I keep seeing the following "warning" on my logs:

> ERROR - 2019-03-20 10:18:31 --> Severity: Warning  -->
>   mssql_connect(): Unable to connect to server: localhost:1433,1433
>   /var/www/html/sseditor/codeigniter/2.1.3/system/database/drivers/mssql/mssql_driver.php
>   63

Here is a snippet of the `mssql_driver.php`:

```
56  function db_connect()
57  {
58      if ($this->port != '')
59      {
60          $this->hostname .= ','.$this->port;
61      }
62
63      return @mssql_connect($this->hostname, $this->username, $this->password);
64  }
```

Does any have a better idea here? I am running out of them :|

Comment: maybe `$db['mssql_local']['hostname'] = 'localhost';`

Comment: @buildok it does not work either `mssql_connect(): Unable to connect to server: localhost,1433` :|

Comment: What is your PHP version?

Comment: @Zhorov PHP Version 5.3.3

Comment: Obvious question -- is SQL Server listening on localhost port 1433?

Comment: @AlexHowansky well I am able to `telnet localhost 1433` so as for me is listening not sure if this is the answer you're looking for though, if you know any command rather than `telner` to proof it is listening let me know about it and I'll be happy to run it and post results.

Comment: Post the lines of code including and preceding the mssql_connect() line.

Comment: @AlexHowansky added to the OP, I am gonna try upgrading CI from 2.1.3 to 2.2.6 which is the latest on 2.x branch and see if that makes it to work.

Comment: Updating to 2.2.6 didn't work either :(

Comment: Note the mssql_* functions were removed for PHP 7.0.0 (Dec 2015) so it's probably not a good idea to start new development with them.

Answer (score 1):

After hours of headache I find out the issue/solution. I was about to delete the question but I prefer to answer myself even if that is becomes a problem for my reputation but I am pretty sure can save someone time and effort.

First thing and I completely forgot to add this part to the OP (apologies for that) apache and PHP are running inside a CentOS VM (Vagrant+VBox).

**The problem:** the guest where the LAMP environment is running didn't know a thing about the host and makes sense.

**The solution:** add the host IP address and the NS to the `/etc/hosts` file on the guest.

```
190.168.56.1    RNDPC\SQLEXPRESS SQLEXPRESS
```

That fixed the issue regarding the following message:

> Unable to connect to server: RNDPC\SQLEXPRESS:1433,1433

A second issue arise related to:

```
RNDPC\SQLEXPRESS:1433,1433
```

Because the driver if the parameter `port` is specified add that `,port`.

**The solution:** remove the port parameter from the `database.php` and "hard code" the port at the end to the `host` definition.

Now my `database.php` looks like:

```
$db['mssql_common']['hostname'] = 'RNDPC\SQLEXPRESS:1433';
$db['mssql_common']['username'] = 'ssUser';
$db['mssql_common']['password'] = '*****';
$db['mssql_common']['database'] = 'ssDB';
$db['mssql_common']['dbdriver'] = 'mssql';
$db['mssql_common']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['mssql_common']['pconnect'] = false;
$db['mssql_common']['db_debug'] = false;
$db['mssql_common']['cache_on'] = false;
$db['mssql_common']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['mssql_common']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['mssql_common']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['mssql_common']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['mssql_common']['autoinit'] = true;
$db['mssql_common']['stricton'] = false;
```

Hope this help someone in the future :)